# At what age is a knight most dangerous?

Tags: humans, combat, medieval

It is a common occurrence in fantasy worlds to have knights, armoured humans fighting with melee weapons. Naturally, as these people age, their reaction times slow down, and as they get very much older they lose their physical strength. However, as they gain experience fighting, they will, surely, grow more skilled.

So, considering a classic human fighter type of person, limiting themselves to fighting up close, at what age would they be most able to fight effectively? Assuming the person trains effectively, including access to optimal diet, for all their life, and does not suffer any debilitating wounds. The technological level can be expressed as "Pre-gunpowder", approximating to the late middle ages. Any weapons and armour that fit that technological level can be used if you judge them to be superior. Culture and status can also be taken to be whatever optimises combat ability.

Comment: I can think of good reasons why 18, 24, 36, 48 and 60 would all be "most dangerous". The inherent problem with this is that these are all opinions based on a query that doesn't really give us much detail to work with. Thank you for specifying the overall health & injury status. We'd also need to know what broad cultural milieu this is, what technological level, what weapons are in use, social caste of the respective fighters, training, nutrition, practice. All sorts of things play into whether one individual can best another.

Comment: @elemtilas edited to include details on requested.

Comment: Culture optimised weapons in different ways, this is still too broad to determine what might constitute a best answer. Under what precise conditions is this one-to one match between undefined warriors to occur? If in the dark, then any peasant with a dagger can (if they know where to strike) defeat the kingdom's champion. Best is defined relative to the exact conditions of the fight and the background - and the competing forces. Tactical capability must be accounted for in a fight with large numbers - take the [Zulu wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Isandlwana), as example.

Comment: @ProjectApex I get that people are different, but there are very broad similarities. Most people, placed in the same circumstances, will peak at roughly the same age in almost any given skill, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Are you asking *by himself* or as a knight in social context? The problem is that as a knight ages, he could also be gathering enough resources to command a group of peasants to fight on both sides of him.

Comment: @DavidR the knight by themself. Else the answer skews towards "whatever age is the wealthiest", which is not particularly helpful.

Comment: The knight by themself - against whom? A million warriors, one, a child with a disarming smile and poison? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood: it's not up to mé to optimise the conditions --- it's up to yóu to provide sufficient background to a) allow us to answer and b) prevent us from offering a wide variety of opinions. So far, you've got two answers and five different opinions. I feel like I'm in an ethnic joke. That's not a good place to be. ( -1 ) So seriously: pick a time frame, choose the weapons, choose the armour, set the scene, describe the character you want the unknown knight to defeat. **THEN** we can better answer your question!

Comment: Erm, knights weren't any sort of one man armies. No part of the army was. You know, by definition. An *effective* army is composed of various people with various weapons and various roles. Knights had one of those. I don't think anybody in their right mind expects deploying *only* knights and expecting to win against any sort of organised enemy. And individual combat prowess pales in comparison to group effectiveness anyway. So when is a knight most dangerous? When surrounded by other troops and not relying solely on their own strength.

Comment: @MegaCrow This reminds me of an alternate history novel I read about, but didn't read. I think it was Hubert's Arthur, by Frederick Rolfe, 1935.  I think I read that in it Arthur I duke of Brittany and heir to the English throne (b.29 March 1187) doesn't die in 1203 but survives and eventually kills King Henry III (b.1 octpber 1207) in a duel and becomes King.  And I couldn't help wondering at what date would their ages be such that a duel between them would be considered a fair fight and not murder.

Comment: @elemtilas The question you suggest makes no sense from an author's POI, because if the author needs a character to win, the character will win against all odds. A question that would make sense is 'At what age a medieval knight reaches the peak fighting prowess?'. It absolutely does not matter who knights are fighting and how they do it. The essence of this question is not calculating the odds of winning but an individual's combat strength.

Comment: @MegaCrow I would suggest editing your question to specify that you are looking for answers related to the individual's combat strength/prowess regardless of the odds of winning. You can also specify that you are talking about a fair 1 vs 1 competition to placate those who overthink things.

Comment: @Otkin -- Well, an "author" can ask author queries on a writing forum! Here at SE they do things different. Questions need to be fairly narrowly focused. This particular one all the more so because the right answer depends on so many variables. It's not my job to provide the variables -- I only do that when I'm asking the question! There's far more than just combat strength involved! "Odds" also have nothing to do with it. OP take heed: if you do edit your query to involve only combat strength, then you've already got your answer: it's the...

Comment: ... fighter who is stronger, regardless of age! That question will be closed for not being about worldbuilding. Bear in mind that your question comes pretty close to that territory as is.

Comment: @elemtilas You are overthinking it. The OP clearly asks: '*considering a classic human fighter type of person, limiting themselves to fighting up close, at what age would they be most able to fight effectively?*'.  In order to answer this question, **you only need to compare the fighting prowess of the same knight at different ages**. Age is a variable that affects fighters due to human biology. As we age our bodies grow weaker and slower. All other variables are unimportant since the OP specifies that their hypothetical knight has optimal training conditions and suffers no health problems.

Comment: @elemtilas If you want to be extremely precise, you can say that combat experience, psychological conditions, weapons, armour, knowledge of one's adversary make a difference. However, most of these are in direct correlation with fighting prowess, moreover, their importance diminishes with age. A 70-year-old fighter does not stand a chance against a 25-year-old fighter unless the gap in skill is truly great. Weapons and armour are a bit trickier, but the OP limits their query to melee combat. Therefore, weapon type does not matter much, only skill. But this covered in optimal training specs.

Comment: @elemtilas A generalised question about the age where the fighting prowess is the highest is more aligned with the proclaimed rule of this stack that the questions should deal with 'rules and systems' of the world. Human biology would be the rule that needs to be applied here. Your directions for the OP are inconsistent with the proclaimed WB.SE rules and will lead to a story-based / opinion-based / circumstantial question that is either off-topic or should be asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

**Mid 20s.**

I looked at average age for Olympic wrestlers, boxers and fencers since those are the three combat sports I could think of.  It is 24, 26 and 26 respectively.  I conclude that this age is where physical prowess and expertise confer the most formidable athletes.

It is not non-intuitive.  Men reach their full muscular growth around that age and 10 years of training is enough to use those muscles.  After that there is no more muscle mass increase (unless you are Sammy Sosa) and an accrual of injuries.

That does not make for very exciting fiction: formidable dude in his mid 20s.  Yes, yes.  What is interesting is the knight who is something other than that - the Ser Jorah / Nolan Ryan of knights.   Or even better the wunderkind knight who is substantially younger than the rest.

Comment: The average age for the top x% would be these ages, but what of the ages of the absolute best, the medal winners for example (weighted or otherwise)?

Comment: Not to invalidate your point but interestingly heavy weight boxer champions ages are a bit higher 28-30. Point for thought but not really applicable to knights fighting. See https://www.boxingforum24.com/threads/average-age-of-heavyweight-champ-opponents.586140/

Answer (score 4):

If everything else is exactly the same (experience, weapons, armour, training, health, etc.) then, as Willk said, a knight will reach their **peak physical prowess at around 25 years old**. *This also assumes that the fight is fair and no underhanded moves are allowed, i.e. it is a contest of pure strength, competition or sparring style*.

In a fight without rules, real battle experience, access to hidden weapons, 'dishonest' moves, and so on will favour a person who has more of them. Still, the upper age limit will probably be around the early 30s unless there is a huge difference in skill levels.

Please also note that historical martial arts are very different from sports. They were optimised toward killing as fast and effective as possible. So, a person with a better grasp of their adversary, timing, distance, and technique has greater odds of winning. The most dangerous knight will be the knight who is more adept at killing using whatever means available.

P.S. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JiwOdoF1vU) discussing the role of strength in armed martial arts. It might give you some ideas.